# что делать если primary key null?

Tags: entity-framework, facade

Здравствуйте я на фасаде формирую запрос и его вывожу на Grid panel Ext js.
Проблема в том что есть одна таблица и там ID null а у меня нет прав его изменять.
в Entity я прописал `@GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)` но особо не помогло что можно сделать?

Comment: В базе данных первичный ключ не может быть Nullable. Если он там прописан как Nullable - значит, это не первичный ключ. Ищите другой первичный ключ...

Comment: Если вас интересует, почему, то по значению первичного ключа строки всегда можно определить конкретную строчку. А `NULL != NULL`.